# Canon SL1 producing dark pictures underwater

Tags: canon, exposure

My Canon Rebel SL1 100d  is taking dark pictures underwater. My old 6mp rebel camera took good pictures at ISO 100, 1/125s and f/6.1. The SL1 sl1 at  ISO 200, 1/60s f/5.6 is still producing dark pictures.

Does this camera need more light than my old camera?

Comment: What depth(s) of water are you talking about? Are you comparing similar situations (i.e., both cameras taking pictures in a backyard pool on a bright sunny day), or are you comparing images from different bodies of water and/or different depths?

Answer (score 4):

"No", your new camera probably doesn't *need* more light.

[ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_speed#Digital_camera_ISO_speed_and_exposure_index), [shutter speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_speed) and [aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture) are the only *internal* factors in the resulting exposure of your image. As they are normalized, they should have the same effect on every camera body.

I suspect that **less light is available in your new environment**, explaining why your previous settings are not working.

Comment: I agree. Especially if the OP is a diver - ligth vanishes surprisingly fast when diving.

Comment: Even the same body of water can have drastically differing amounts of light at the same depths at different times. Variables include (but are not limited to): cloud cover (how much light is hitting the top of the water affects how much light is at any particular depth), the concentration of light absorbing particulates in the water (e.g. mud after a rainstorm), the time of day (the angle of the sun), etc.

Comment: Two dive trips with this camera. The pictures are darker than my old camera at these same places

Comment: A lot of factors are in play. If you want a definitive answer, take your old camera and compare the picture it takes to your new one, using the same setting in a controlled environment.